# Hosting error 500

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, hosting, ovh

I have a shared hosting with a wordpress project in it. I'm trying to redirect a domain to the hosting IP address. The problem is that I get an error 500 when I try to access the domain. 
I have tried increasing the php memory limit, tried to change the permissions of the folders/files to 755, checked the syntax of the .htaccess file... I just can't get it to work. 
The weird thing is that if I access it from the subdomain the hosting gives me, I can access it just fine. It's just the redirect that is not right. Also, if I remove the .htaccess file, I get a 404 error on index.php.

Does someone have an idea of what might be causing this?

Comment: This is off topic here, as it is about hosting, not about programming

Comment: please check database url